# If we know $x \sec \theta$ and $x \operatorname{cosec} \theta$, is it possible to derive an expression for $x$ and $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Suppose we know $x \sec \theta = a$ and $x \operatorname{cosec} \theta = b$.

Is it possible to derive an expression for $x$ and $\theta$? I know that we can find $\theta$ (and then $x$) from an intersection of the plots, but is a trigonometric expression possible?

[image]

I have spent many days on this problem, but am unable to find a solution. Could the experts here please guide me if/when free? My knowledge of trigonometric identities is decent, so I would gratefully embrace even a hint.

[Having stopped formal education a decade ago, I beg you to not doubt this as a request for homework help.]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Leaving special cases where some of the terms are zero, and recalling the definitions of $\sec$ and $\mathrm{cosec}$, your equations become $a\cos\theta = x = b\sin\theta$.  Then $x^2/a^2 + x^2/b^2=1$ from which you can find up to two solutions for $x$.  Dividing you also find $\tan\theta = a/b$ which in general has multiple solutions.  Hope this helps.  PS, the plots look like $a\cos\theta$ and $b\sin\theta$ since neither blows up to $\infty$.

Comment: @WADon Very grateful to you  Yes, the plots are of $a \cos \theta$ and $b \sin \theta$. The intersection gives $x$. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Somehow, I was squaring and adding and subtracting and dividing etc. In short, trying to use the other identities $1+\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta$ etc.

Comment: @Ritesh Looks like someone got there first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\cos\left(  \theta\right)  }  & =a\tag{1}\\
\frac{x}{\sin\left(  \theta\right)  }  & =b\tag{2}
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(  \theta\right)    & =\frac{x}{a}\\
\sin\left(  \theta\right)    & =\frac{x}{b}
\end{align*}
Since
$$
1=\cos^{2}\left(  \theta\right)  +\sin^{2}\left(  \theta\right)
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
1  & =\left(  \frac{x}{a}\right)  ^{2}+\left(  \frac{x}{b}\right)  ^{2}\\
1  & =x^{2}\left(  \frac{1}{a^{2}}+\frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)  \\
& =x^{2}\left(  \frac{b^{2}+a^{2}}{a^{2}b^{2}}\right)
\end{align*}
Solving for $x$ gives
\begin{align}
x^{2}  & =\frac{a^{2}b^{2}}{b^{2}+a^{2}}\nonumber\\
x  & =\pm\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
To find $\theta$, we divide (1) by (2)
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{x}{\cos\left(  \theta\right)  }}{\frac{x}{\sin\left(
\theta\right)  }}  & =\frac{a}{b}\\
\tan\theta & =\frac{a}{b}\\
\theta & =\arctan\left(  \frac{a}{b}\right)
\end{align*}
This assumes $a>0,b>0$.

Comment: Truly very grateful to you and the commenting person. Somehow, this was a complete blindspot for me.